# Accounting for rounding mode in a constexpr function

Tags: c++, floating-point, rounding

I am trying to write a `constexpr` version of the `exp` function. I know that

- The algorithm I'm using is designed for `FE_TONEAREST` rounding
- Since C++11, it's possible to change the rounding mode via `fesetround( int round )` (provided that `#pragma STDC FENV_ACCESS` is supported and is set to `ON`)
- I am not allowed to call the non-constexpr function `fesetround(int)` within my own `constexpr` function

If my understanding is correct, this means that (within a compiler that supports `#pragma STDC FENV_ACCESS`), a user would be allowed to set the rounding mode before calling my function, but my function would not be allowed to un-do this change (even temporarily) and could therefore be excuted with the wrong rounding mode.

**The best option that I can come up with** for handling this is to have two functions:

- Version A is marked `constexpr` and does not set the rounding mode
- Version B is *not* marked `constexpr` and does 3 things:

  1. Set the rounding mode to `FE_TONEAREST`
  2. Call Version A
  3. Reset the rounding mode
  4. Return the result of Version A

To set a `constexpr` variable, one would have to call version A, but it would always be evaluated as though the rounding mode were `FE_TONEAREST` since (according to [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/fenv/FE_round)):

> The current rounding mode does NOT affect .... results of
>   floating-point arithmetic operators in constant expressions (always to
>   nearest)

In non-constexpr `contexts`, Version A and Version B would agree so long as the rounding mode were `FE_TONEAREST`, but Version B would provide a superior result for any other rounding mode. The onus would be on the user to either use `FE_TONEAREST` rounding *or* make sure to call Version B.

**Is there a better way of handling this, within standard C++?** ... or does the standard have other things to say about rounding modes which make this entire question moot?

**Edit:** My goal isn't to *respect* the rounding mode; it's to *ignore* it so that the function's accuracy is consistent. I would prefer to use only Version B, but it's not possible to change the rounding mode in a `constexpr` function.

Comment: So the result of calling Version A (if it wasn't a `constexpr`) could/should vary depending on the rounding mode?

Comment: Yes; the algorithm does floating point addition/multiplication, so in a non-`constexpr` context I would expect it to respect the rounding mode

Comment: So you expect a compile time constant to have different values at run time?  It can't.  You can have different `constexpr` values, which you pick from at run time, or you can calculate it (using the current rounding mode) at run time.

Comment: @user1476176: Your statement that “I would expect it to respect the rounding mode” is ambiguous due to the nature of English. It is not clear whether you mean you expect the value would differ because the rounding mode would **in fact** affect the operations or you mean you **desire** the result to depend on the rounding mode.

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm: See my comment above.

Comment: @EricPostpischil I meant that my knowledge of C++ leads me to believe that the rounding mode would affect the intermediate operations. I do not want this behaviour.

Answer (score 1):

The `FENV_ACCESS` feature provided by C and C++ is a kludge and does not support the use sought in this question. Programs that modify the rounding mode are rare, and language support for them is poor.

Per the C standard (and inherited by C++ by reference), `FENV_ACCESS` informs the implementation the program might run under non-default floating-point control modes. If you allow your `exp` function to be called while in a non-default mode and it is not translated with `FENV_ACCESS` on, the standards do not tell us what the behavior will be.

Further, C++ does not provide any means by which different versions of a routine would be automatically called depending on the rounding mode or the state of `FENV_ACCESS` (although C++ implementations might do so as an extension to the language).

The statement you refer to from [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/fenv/FE_round) that the rounding mode does not affect arithmetic operations in constant expressions appears to be a conclusion derived by cppreference, not something explicitly stated in the C++ standard. Perhaps it follows from the fact that constant expressions are evaluated at translation time, so no modification of the floating-point environment could have been performed. However, it is not clear to me this is completely guaranteed by the standard—a note in the expr.const section says “Constant expressions can be evaluated during translation.” It does not say they must be evaluated during translation.

Generally, one would not want `exp` to behave the same way when the rounding mode is to-nearest as when it is toward-infinity or another setting. Instead, one would want `exp` to return a rounded-up result when the mode is toward-infinity, rounded-down when the mode is toward-negative-infinity, and rounded toward zero when the mode is toward-zero. (Obtaining these results requires having different implementations of `exp` for each mode, since merely applying rounding to each operation it does would not produce the required result.) So your request that `exp` return the same result regardless of rounding mode is a bit unusual. What purpose does it serve to return a rounded-to-nearest result when the program is evaluating floating-point operations with a different rounding mode? If a program is using toward-infinity to try to calculate an upper bound, a to-nearest `exp` would break that calculation.

Comment: "If you allow your exp function to be called while in a non-default mode and it is not translated with FENV_ACCESS on, the standards do not tell us what the behavior will be." Is there a way of prohibiting my function from being called with non-default modes (beyond aborting if the rounding mode is not to-nearest)? Also, remember that this function is `constexpr` and thus `inline` - it will always be translated with the client code, i.e., with the same state of `FENV_ACCESS` as the client code uses.

Comment: (2) "C++ does not provide any means by which different versions of a routine would be automatically called depending on the rounding mode" - What about `switch(fegetround()) { case FE_DOWNWARD: ... case FE_UPWARD: .... }` ? This can't be done within a `constexpr` function, but otherwise it works, no?

Comment: (3) "your request that exp return the same result regardless of rounding mode is a bit unusual." - glibc's implementation does this. It sets the rounding mode to to-nearest, performs its intermediate calculations, then resets the rounding mode and returns (https://code.woboq.org/userspace/glibc/sysdeps/ieee754/dbl-64/e_exp.c.html). I would do the same, but I can't change the rounding mode in a `constexpr` function. My goal isn't to *respect* the rounding mode; it's to *ignore* it so that the function's accuracy is consistent.

Comment: Cppreference took that from C standard, F.8.2. To be fair, it is simplified (in C, the expression has to be part of static or thread local initializer)

Comment: @Cubbi: C F.8.2 says round-to-nearest is in effect during translation. That is not the same as saying a `constexpr` uses round-to-nearest. The C++ standard says, in a note, constant expressions **can be** evaluated during translation, but I do not see that it says they **are** evaluated during translation. So there is no explicit statement that constant expressions are evaluated with round-to-nearest. It is a conclusion drawn by cppreference.

Comment: @EricPostpischil yes, that's why I edited that page to say "at compile time" instead.